# Google Chrome update to 37 makes text look slightly bolder

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Just updated to Chrome 37 and the Segoe UI Lighter font I use for my website looks a little bolder. Is it possible to correct this?

this example shows it:

```
<h1 style="font-family: Segoe UI Light, Segoe UI; font-weight: lighter">
    The <i>quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</i>
</h1>
```

In Internet Explorer 9, Safari 5, and Opera 21 it looks as desired - and in previous versions of Chrome it did too. But in Chrome 37 it's slightly bolder - presumably because of the DirectWrite switch (?).

Comment: thats likely why. theres been a number of visual changes.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I also had this problem: http://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/2en8j0/ . Pretty sure they are related

Comment: Try adding this to the font-style "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;"

Comment: FYI Now on Chrome 38 aand it appears to have been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a bug in version 37 that prevents Chrome from rendering Segoe UI Light.  See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408587

What's happening is that it can't render Segoe UI Light for whatever reason, so it goes to the next fallback font (Segoe UI), which it can render.  That's why your text looks slightly bolder.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the font-style you're having issues with.

```
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

I think the difference you're seeing has to do with when you specify light as oppose to the weight of say, 300. So the browser's might render them differently too. So if that doesn't work, also try and specify the actual weight desired

Comment: Doesn't make any difference unfortunately - but I found font which looks the same: WeblySleek UI Light

Comment: Oh, I had that same issue, so thought it could help. Good you found an alternative solution, anyhow. Best of luck.

Comment: Update: Using a font that gets downloaded causes the layout out to shift slightly once the font has been downloaded. Don't like that so I might can the idea. Once the font has been cached it's OK, but for the front page - hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm...

Comment: (Another) update: Chrome Canary seems to be better. Maybe its been fixed. Though the canary version is the same as the stable version so I'm dubious.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that adding this to the font-style will correct it.

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```